# Rails namespaced routes work in development but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes, production-environment

I'm trying to nest some routes under the namespace, account.

I want user management under account like `/account/users` and `/account/users/5/edit`

In routes.rb:

```
namespace :account do
  resources :users do
    member do
      put 'generate_api_key'
    end 

    collection do
      post 'api_key'
    end 
  end 
end
```

My controllers are not namespaced or put them in any different directory.

```
/app
  /controllers
    accounts_controller.rb
    users_controller.rb
```

In my development environment this is working fine, but **in production I get 404 responses to any of the `/account/users...` paths** (which, by the way, are all still generated correctly: `new_account_users_path`, `edit_account_user_path`, etc).

`rake routes` generates the same output in both environments. Here is the relevant bit:

```
 generate_api_key_account_user PUT    /account/users/:id/generate_api_key(.:format)                      {:action=>"generate_api_key", :controller=>"account/users"}
         api_key_account_users POST   /account/users/api_key(.:format)                                   {:action=>"api_key", :controller=>"account/users"}
                 account_users GET    /account/users(.:format)                                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"account/users"}
                               POST   /account/users(.:format)                                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"account/users"}
              new_account_user GET    /account/users/new(.:format)                                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"account/users"}
             edit_account_user GET    /account/users/:id/edit(.:format)                                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account/users"}
                  account_user GET    /account/users/:id(.:format)                                       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"account/users"}
                               PUT    /account/users/:id(.:format)                                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"account/users"}
                               DELETE /account/users/:id(.:format)                                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"account/users"}
```

Given that the routes seem to look for the `Users` controller in the `/account` subdirectory, I suppose my question is why does this work in development?

Production is:

- Rails 3.0.7
- Passenger
- Apache

Development is:

- Rails 3.0.7
- Mongrel

Thanks for your thoughts on this one.

Comment: You're writing "I get 404 responses to any of the `/admin/users`... paths". Do you mean `/accounts/users`?

Comment: You're quite right - typo there. I've edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're namespacing like this, Rails requires the controllers to be at their correct paths, such as `app/controllers/account/users_controller.rb`. If you don't want to do this, then use `scope` instead:

```
scope :path => "account" do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: The issue is that in development it'll actually use the controller in the main path in the absence of a properly named controller in the proper path.  Kind of confusing.

Comment: Um... that's why I said you could use namespace if you want them to be at a specific path, or scope if not.